# TFS 2005 Wiki Template?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2005, tfs, wiki

Is there a Wiki plugin for TFS 2005, ie. SharePoint Services 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgraded to TFS2008 then you could use a Sharepoint Services 3.0 portal which includes a basic Wiki feature.  There are many other reasons to upgrade to TFS2008 (less bugs, better speed, more features, great back-compat with VS2005 etc) but just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one here: http://www.neoworks.com/products/sharepoint/wikipoint/index.html 
I do not know how good it is, but you can install a demo and try it out.